# Long Press InkResponse not working when using Container with Decoration

Tags: dart, flutter

Long Press InkResponse not working when using Container with Decoration

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13421

```
return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: new Column(
```

or

```
return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: new Column(
```

(both are identical)

If I comment color, everything goes back to normal.

It is the same for **image** property.

**But not** for the **border** property.

I placed a **GestureDetector** over **Container** to see if the gestures are detected,
there was no problem with the detection, its just the **long press** animations that are not working.

I could also confirm this **without** using the GestureDetector, I can Hear the **Tapping Sound** from the Emulator when doing a **long press** or a **tap**.

**Temporary Workaround** is to use **Scaffold**

```
return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Column(
```

Comment: don't double scaffold hit strange bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the docs say:

> The InkResponse widget must have a Material widget as an ancestor. The
>   Material widget is where the ink reactions are actually painted. This
>   matches the material design premise wherein the Material is what is
>   actually reacting to touches by spreading ink.

So I added a Material ancestor to the Container.

```
new Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Column(
```

Comment: btw, here is the original bug report https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3782